# Node deployment to heroku fails

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy a basic app to heroku and i am getting an error. I have included heroku log.

```
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082630+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server/server.js'
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082632+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082634+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082635+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082651+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2018-08-12T11:19:35.082653+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
2018-08-12T11:19:35.165790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-12T11:19:35.168329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-08-12T11:19:38.372891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server/server.js`
2018-08-12T11:19:40.669347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-08-12T11:19:40.685006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573913+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:538
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573936+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573938+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573940+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573942+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server/server.js'
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573943+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573945+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573947+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573949+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
2018-08-12T11:19:40.573951+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I have included the start script like this

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node server/server.js",
"test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\""
},
```

please tell me what i am missing. I have also attached my root directory folders image.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNxgu.png)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you are already using Procfile, you can specify there:
`web: node server/server.js`

By default, Heroku looks into the Profice first in order to start server. And only then it looks into package.json's start script.